# Issue with the name of cache directory in Android

Tags: java, android, caching, android-file

In my app I am saving temporary files to my app cache folder. I am getting the name of the cache directory via this method:

```
context.getCacheDir();
```

It returns me such path:  **/data/user/0/my.app.packagename**
But later when I am trying to get name of parent directory of my cache file via this method - **file.getParent();** I am getting absolutely different path to cache directory, in my case this: **/data/data/my.app-packagename**

So I am just wondering why this is happening, why `getParent()` doesn't return the same path as `context.getCacheDir()`?

Comment: Could you provide the source code (fragment)?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour is correct, technically its the same.
If you connect to your android device via adb shell and go into /data/user/ and run the 'll' command you will see that the folder 0 is just a symbolic link to /data/data/.

```
root@android:/data/user # ll
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1970-01-01 01:00 0 -> /data/data/
```

If you dont know what that means, read up on [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

So there is no issue and you can trust android that they are the same.

Comment: Thanks) In my case i was trying to check that my file is in cache. I was doing it via comparing two strings, such as file.getParent().startsWith(context.getCacheDir()). And i always got false, because of 0 character in path)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior confused me a lot today.
Here are my 50 Cent to bring light into this:

1. I've started an Emulator with Android 8.1
2. I've connected my Android 9 Device via USB

After that I've  started Android-Studio and opend the *Device File Explorer*.

**Now strange things happend:**

- On Android 8.1 you see the structure */data/user/0/com.myApp/*
- on Android 9 there is no directory /data/user (and no symbolic link visible via android-studio)

**BUT**, internally the path seems to be the same (even if there is no symbolic Link visible in android studio).

I use RNFetchBlob (React native package to read files), and if I output the Result from `RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.CacheDir` the result was */data/user/0/....* even if on Android 9 this Directory not exist.
But I'd gave it a try and output all files that will be found at this Directory with the following Command :

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.CacheDir)
    .then((files) => {
      console.log("output-files",files);
    })
```

...and found that this output all the files I've cached before.

If anybody knows some documentation why this behavior exist up from Android 9, please comment and point us to this.